# How can Midnight Commander be used to change to a different directory?

Tags: directory, command-line-interface

Switching and moving around directories from the command line is awkward in the shell, and I want to use an utility like Midnight Commander to move between directories.

In effect I want to use MC to navigate to a directory, than close it or hide it in some way so I have access to the normal shell prompt.

Does it have that option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ctrl-O` hides the panels temporarily.

Comment: I wanted to know how to do an equivalent of cd so I could exit mc and be in that directory, but Ctrl-O is good enough. It beats excessive and awkwared cd commands

Comment: NOTE that CTRL-O in effect starts a NEW shell, under MC's control. This may not behave entirely like you would expect a new shell to behave. MOst distros include an mc start script that preserves the CWD on exit, though - so check if you already have this.

Comment: Staying in the selected directory in MC is what I want prefer or at least have it as an option. Ubuntu Lucid reverts to the directory I started MC in and I want the option of staying in the selected directory